# Remove and add osgi bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-felix, equinox, bndtools

Eclipse + plugin:bndtools 
Starting system with bndrun file.
Apache Felix Web Console to start/stop bundle.

I want to modify a class in a bundle and reload the bundle only without restarting the whole system. From the web console I unistall the bundle and then I install it indicating the new bundle jar. But something goes wrong.
Maybe because that bundle depends on others?. how can I understand the dependencies between the bundles?

Comment: "Something goes wrong"... not the most helpful description of the problem.

Comment: Rest calls do not work anymore...for example. I want understand the correct way to update a bundle when the server is started.

Comment: The `Bundle` class has an `update` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload a bundle with the `update` command in your OSGi shell.

Find the id of your bundle and use `update <id>`. It will reload the bundle without restarting the whole system. Other bundles might restart if they have a static dependency on your updated bundle though.